# MVC Core Razor Model property is null

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm running into an issue with my Razor view pages where the Model (capital M) property is null.
e.g. A line in the view resembling:

`My name is @Model.Name`

will null reference exception on Model

But code like this still works fine:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
```

**I'm hoping to get an idea of what is required for Model to be populated properly.**

My view does have the needed `@model` command at the top.

Comment: Is the "Name" property exist inside your ViewModel? please share your controller and model class

Comment: Afraid I can't post actual code, it's government work.  Suffice it to say that yes the name property is in the view model.

Comment: Check your model type defined in @model command. may be it is not identical with controller aspect model.

Comment: Show the `return ....` line from the Action method in the `Controller` class - it should return the model object that you created there. One such line can't be THAT secret. Or if you think it is then maybe this is not the site for you because *enough code is required in questions like this for us to reproduce or at least analyze the issue*.